# GSheets: Script running very slowly and sometimes not performing task on all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IDeRrQkJLohGtPf8sEgnG-jUGx2IrXx5VhE-L-GkjQk/edit#gid=95001936)

I've the following script which is supposed to enable me to control the columns to Hide/Unhide on specific sheets (A,B,C,D,E). There is a trigger on opening the sheet. If I run the script from the Script editor, it does perform the task, sheet after sheet very very slowly. However If I try on opening the spreadsheet, it starts with sheet A, then B, but does not complete it in B. Knowing that currently users are not inputting data, I wonder if this is the best approach (fearing to have at the end a spreadsheet which runs calculations and this script very slowly)

Could you please help with this little task ? I don't know much about writing scripts, this is merely few copy/paste from what I was able to find on the internet,

I appreciate your time!

**Basically**: I'm trying to control which week to show, I would show week 1 and hide the rest, then the following week, I would show Week 2 and hide the rest, etc...

**Script**

```
function hideColumnsOnSheet(sheetName) {
var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
b.showColumns(1, b.getMaxColumns());
b.getRange('4:4')
    .getValues()[0]
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r && r == 'x') b.hideColumns(i + 1)
    });
}
function onOpen() {

hideColumnsOnSheet("A");
hideColumnsOnSheet("B");
hideColumnsOnSheet("C");
hideColumnsOnSheet("D");
hideColumnsOnSheet("E");
}
```

Comment: Simple triggers (such as `function onOpen(e)`) are limited in run time to 30 seconds: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions You should refactor the approach to first develop contiguous ranges of columns that should be hidden and then use whichever of the [`hideColumns()` methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumn(Range)) for those sets of ranges. Currently, you call `hideColumns()` once for individual columns, which, as you note, is slow.

Comment: Thank you for your support and indications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse your original way to reduce the expensive API calls. Hide all columns at beginning, find the first and last column with space in row 4, and then show all columns in between, I've revised the method like below:

**Update**

Regrading to that all columns cannot be hid at beginning, we reverse the method back, but still reduce to only two `hideColumns()` API call.

```
function hideColumnsOnSheet(sheetName) {

    var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    b.showColumns(1, b.getMaxColumns());

    var visibleColumn = [];

    b.getRange('J4:4').getValues()[0].forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r != 'x') {
            visibleColumn.push(i + 1);   
        }
    });

    var freezeColumnsNum = 9;
    var indexOfFirstShowColumn = parseInt(visibleColumn[0] + freezeColumnsNum);
    var indexOfLastShowColumn = parseInt(visibleColumn.pop() + freezeColumnsNum);

    if (indexOfFirstShowColumn != (freezeColumnsNum + 1)) {
        b.hideColumns(freezeColumnsNum + 1, (indexOfFirstShowColumn - 1) - freezeColumnsNum);
    }

    b.hideColumns(indexOfLastShowColumn + 1, (b.getMaxColumns() - 
   indexOfLastShowColumn));
}   

function onOpen(e) {

    hideColumnsOnSheet("A");
    hideColumnsOnSheet("B");
    hideColumnsOnSheet("C");
    hideColumnsOnSheet("D");
    hideColumnsOnSheet("E");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help, All columns are hidden as you suggested, then I've copied your script and I get this error [You can't hide all the columns on the sheet. (line 3, file "Code")]

Comment: @Nabnub, sorry about that, let me revise the answer.

Comment: Do you think adding this task (script) will slow down the whole spreadsheet? because I've got plenty calculations running (as you probably noticed) when users will start using it. In fact I will have many spreadsheets like this one, and I will have an ImportRange function in each one of them to retrieve those values from a master sheet.

Comment: @Nabnub, it would not affect the performance of original interaction (from user input and as you said a lot of calculation). And this method need to take some time but I think not really much if your column won't grow too many. Just by reducing the API call, I think the thing is fine. FYI, I have updated the answer, maybe you could just have a try.

Comment: @ Carr, Thanks a lot for your efforts. I've updated the script, then all columns were initially not hidden, but I get this error [Cannot convert NaN to (class). (line 15, file "Code")]

Comment: @Nabnub, I need your test again.

Comment: @ Carr, I've copied your latest update again (with parseInt) , but still I get the same error [Cannot convert NaN to (class). (line 15, file "Code")]. sorry for this annoying issue.

Comment: @ Carr You've done a great job. Script is running on all sheets and at the speed of light. I really appreciate the time that you have given and your efforts to solve the issues. Thank you very much

Comment: @Nabnub, my pleasure :)